# ZXing Embedded center horizontal prompt

Tags: android, android-manifest, zxing, android-theme, android-styles

Well, had this doubt and found a simple solution. I'll share it below.
 [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a style:

```
<style name="ZxingTheme" parent="zxing_CaptureTheme">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
</style>
```

Override in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/ZxingTheme"
    tools:replace="screenOrientation, theme" />
```

Result:
[image]